# Specify a single gke cluster for gcp error reporting service

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-stackdriver, google-cloud-error-reporting

I've multiple gke clusters (stg, dev, prod), And I'm using the [error reporting service](https://cloud.google.com/error-reportingerror) to get alerts about errors, so is there anyway to filter the errors based on the gke cluster name, e.g (getting only errors from the prod cluster)

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is: this is not possible with Error Reporting because there are only a few [text matching](https://cloud.google.com/error-reporting/docs/viewing-errors#text_matching) filters that can be applied, and none of them could be used as a cluster's identifier.

Being said that, there is a way to get alerts for the errors seen in [Cloud Logging](https://cloud.google.com/logging) for a particular cluster. Just run the following query in the [Cloud Logging Logs Explorer](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/logs-explorer-interface) using your own cluster's name:

```
resource.type="k8s_pod"
resource.labels.cluster_name="your-cluster-name"
jsonPayload.message:"error"
```

Once run, click on the "create alert" button; a walk-through wizard will appear where you can customize it by setting up timers, notification channels, etc.

Comment: Thanks for ur answer,
Regarding the second part I've used this way in multiple scenarios, but in this case I get a lot of errors and using this will cause a lot of errors alerts to be sent.

Comment: @AhmedElsherbiny the errors seen in Error Reporting and in Cloud Logging are the same, the only difference is that in Error Reporting aregruped based on the error type by default, same thing you can do in Cloud Logging by [setting up the propper filters](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/building-queries).

Comment: I know that errors exists in log explorer and cloud logging, but error reporting group errors then send a report of them, I think that is not feasible by cloud logging, So if there is a way to do so will be a great solution for my case.

Comment: Sure it is feasible in cloud logging, you can customize the filter to catch wheteaver level of error you want and then create an alert just for that filter, Im not going into the details on how to do that as it would be a new question for you to ask. Consider upvoting or accept the answer if it was useful to you.